# OS X server: Is it possible to customize xcode service notification email content

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, continuous-integration, osx-server

Is it possible to customize the contents of the email OS X server sends after integrating bot?
I would like to include commit text in the notification email so that people know what was changed between builds.